# How I can use External Accessory Framework in Xcode for connect and send a stream to a Bluetooth Printer?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, stream, external-accessory

I want to build an iOS App with XCode that can connect to a Bluetooth Printer and print some text. For this I referenced **External Accessory Framework**. I want to only connect and send a stream (string) to this for printing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference.pdf

I referenced the above link but didn't quite understand on how to use it. Please guide me on how to use it to achieve what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the printer certified under the MFI program and does the vendor provide an SDK?  If the answer to either of those questions is "no" then you won't be able to connect using the external accessory framework

Comment: yes it is MFI certified...

Comment: http://www.bixolon.com/html/en/download/download_product.xhtml?prod_id=18     here is the sdk from the printer company but my chef want that I built only two functions for connect and print and string...but I develop in c# and java and xcode is new for my  :( that is my Problem

Comment: The manual in the SDK shows how to add the external accessory framework and the supported devices to your project Info.plist.  The SDK from the printer vendor then adds the objects you need to talk to the printer.  You don't need to interact with the External Accessory framework directly